# Demonstrate spoofing with GNSS SDR sim

Tags: gps, spoofing

Is it possible to demonstrate GPS spoofing with GNSS SDR sim or GPS SDR sim? I found multiple examples with real antennas, but I would like to do it virtually (in SDR).

EDIT:
I found multiple examples on forums threads that this is possible, but I still can't find any tutorial or something similar. My problem is that GPS-sdr-sim generates `.bin` file which is probably not correct format for GNSS-SDR. When I run it with `gnsdr.conf`, I get messages for duration of generated signal:

> Current receiver time: 1 s
>
> Tracking of GPS L1 C/A signal started on 3 for satellite GPS PRN 19 (Block IIR)
>
> Tracking of GPS L1 C/A signal started on channel 2 for satellite GPS PRN 26 (Block IIF)
>
> Loss of lock in channel 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, only thing that was wrong is sampling processing which is defined in GNSS-SDR as
`SignalSource.sampling_frequency=4000000`, while in GPS-SDR is 2600000 by default. So the solution is add `-s 4000000` in GPS-SDR command.

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple examples on forums thread how it is possible, but I still can't find any tutorial or something similar. My problem is that GPS-sdr-sim generates .bin file which is probably not correct for GNSS-SDR.

Comment: Seems more like a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: It is not full answer, but part of question is it possible?

Comment: It would be better to **edit** your question and add this part too.

Comment: thanks, I can remove this comments, if you think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just some semantics, when you say "virtually" it means to generate a file with gps-sdr-sim and use that file as an input to GNSS-SDR.
If you take that file and use hackrf_transfert with the HackRF One (a software-defined radio), you physically generate RF signals that are sent over the air.